# how to use java native (cacls) for change file permission in windows

Tags: java, windows, native, file-permissions

i had tried these syntax , but why it didn't work?

i really glad for your advice.

thanks before. sorry for bad english.

package priviledge;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 *
 * @author DINA
 */
public class Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
     File f = new File("C:/lala/images1.jpg");
     permission(f);
}

public static  void permission(File src) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
// win32 command line variant
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cacls 000 " + src.getPath());
p.waitFor(); // p.waitFor()

Comment: What happened? What did you get?

Comment: i purpose that , these syntax can change the file permission as mention  path on these syntax.

Comment: i get nothing. when i check the file (images1.jpg) in windows explorer, the permission of the file is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Because `cacls` works differently from `chmod`. In particular, the first argument is a file name (which would mean you try doing that on a file named `000`). Windows using ACLs further comlpicates things as they don't fit as nicely into three octal numbers.

Look up the documentation of `cacls` (just type it at the command prompt) and fix your command line.

Comment: i did it, but , i can't understand about cacls help in commandprompt. if i want to change file permission for group, what should i type in java code?

Answer (score 1):

for cacls a group is the same as a user so for example to grant Full permission to the ABC group you would type "cacls filename /g ABC:F" You can view more details on the documentation of cacls

Comment: the file name have to complete with its path?

Comment: yes as another example to do `cacls C:\lala\images1.jpg /E /g ABC:R` you write `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cacls "+src.getPath()+" /E /g ABC:R");`

Comment: well, if i want to make the username will be dynamis, i mean without type in the syntax, what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

I was also working on a project which Involves changing Permissions of a folder. I tried many methods, but didn't work as I was expecting, So, I came up with a new Idea. For That you need basic knowledge about Batch files,

I wanted to change permission of a folder, So, This is what I did:

Created a text file, Wrote the commands in that file, Converted it into a batch file, and executed it using:

```js
 File file = new File("server.bat");
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```

(Works for java 1.6 or newer), Deleted that batch file.

It may be a long way to do that, But in this method can execute any number of commands at a single shot. With this method, You don't have to worry about working directory as you can change it in the batch file. This may be a bad idea, I am new to java, But I told You my idea.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the Q at all.